# RecyclerView highlight item on click

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I created the following `RecyclerView` dynamically. I want to highlight the clicked item while clicking in it. After click, it goes to the next `Activity`. I have given the background XML below:

```
hRecyclerView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mylistview_background);
```

Is this not the way to set it? What should I do here?

```
        hRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_history_view);

        // use a linear layout manager
        hLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        hRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(hLayoutManager);
        hRecyclerView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        hRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
        hRecyclerView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mylistview_background);
   hAdapter = new HistoryAdapter(history, this);
        hRecyclerView.setAdapter(hAdapter);


        hRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        // do whatever
                        if(position>0) {
                            History his = history.get(position - 1);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TrackActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("from", his.src_station);
                            intent.putExtra("to", his.dest_station);
                            intent.putExtra("train_no", his.train_no);
                            intent.putExtra("train_name", his.train_name);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);

                        }
                    }
                })
        );

        hRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

mylistview_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <gradient android:endColor="#22000000" android:startColor="#a7a2288f" android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape>
            <gradient android:endColor="#2200ff00" android:startColor="#a2008f00" android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </item>


</selector>
```

Any help is much Appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using an onClickListenner in your ViewHolder class to handle click events ? I spent a lot of time yesterday to come up with the best solution for such case and to me it's easier that way. If there is something I'm not aware of please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the background of your entire RecyclerView (Which doesn't get 'selected').  You need to be setting the background of your row view.  In onCreateViewHolder in HistoryAdapter, you'll be inflating the row view.  *THAT* is the background that needs to have a selector drawable (You can set it in the xml, or in code).

Answer (score 0):

```
hRecyclerView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mylistview_background);
```

First delete this line, it's for the entire recyclerview.

Your custom row / item layout should look like this (put mylistview_background.xml in the drawable folder ) :

```
<RelativeLayout ...
     android:background="@drawable/mylistview_background">...
</RelativeLayout>
```